# Firewall configuration for NFS share of ZFS mirror

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, zfs, ufw

I have several Ubuntu Server 16.04 VMs. One of these is my fileserver and has a ZFS mirror. I want to mount filesystems in the mirror to various different client VMs. I can successfully do so when the firewall (ufw) is disabled using something like this:

```
mount -t nfs4 server:/tank/filesystem /filesystem
```

As well as when configuring them to mount at boot with `/etc/fstab`, but when I `ufw enable` and allow traffic to my local subnet

```
ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 2049
```

the connection is refused by the server.

According to my searches, NFS v4 should only need this port and only over TCP. I have seen various guides/posts enabling an assortment of ports for older versions of NFS, but this seems to me to be unnecessary. I have also seen a few guides on setting up the nfs server by modifying `/etc/exports`, but I was under the impression that nfs configurations at the server level were not required when the nfs share is being handled by ZFS.

So I guess my question is:
**If my goal is to mount a ZFS filesystem using nfs on local subnet client VMs, what is the best way to configure the firewall and/or nfs-server to enable this?**

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the exports in `/etc/exports` are in fact required:

```
/tank/filesystem1    192.168.1.XXX(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

After restarting the nfs-kernel-server, the shares mounted with the above command. Now to figure out the permissions...